# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python27\python.exe"

Tags: python

I have a question. I work on Windows  10.

I done a reinstall of my installed pythons. On my PC i had Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.6. I uninstalled Python 2.7. Then, i reinstalled Python 3.6.6.

When i want to write `pip install numpy` etc, i get this error:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python27\python.exe" ...

When i deleted that path from system `PATH`, i still get that error.

`python -m pip install something` works, when i type `python` in `cmd` i get `python 3.6.6 promprt` but my question is, can i delete taht error from windows `cmd`? If i cant, if this error will affect on my compiling, debugging and pythone code working?